# MySQL: Insert into one table if not exists; if it does, drop it and insert it into another table

Tags: mysql

First, my basic structure is as follows.

`friends` table, with some sample relationships added:

```
-------------------------------
|user1 | user2 | util1 | util2|
-------------------------------
| 123  |  456  |  123  |  456 |
| 789  |  012  |  012  |  789 |
| 345  |  678  |  345  |  678 |
```

(The `util` columns are helper columns associated with a trigger I have--if, say, `(user1,user2) = (123,456)` exists, then I don't want `(456,123)` to be able to be created. The trigger inserts `(util1,util2)` as `(least,greatest)`; then there's a unique index on that. This is fine, just figured I'd explain that.)

`friendReq` table of pending friend requests:

```
----------------
|initBy| reqTo |
----------------
| 901  |  234  |
| 567  |  890  |
| 234  |  567  |
```

What works: if, say, user of id `901` requests `234`, this request is added to the friend request table if it doesn't already exist; I have a unique index on `(initBy,reqTo)`, so if `901` resends a request to `234` it won't insert and extra row. Cool.

What I need: if `234` subsequently sends a request to `901`, I don't want `(initBy,reqTo) = (234, 901)` to be inserted (note that I already have it set up that when `901` requests `234`, `234` receives a notification; this works fine. Here I am just supposing that `234` ignores the request and decides to try to add `901` manually via my simple text field + add friend button). Instead, I want it to automatically accept the friends request--that is, delete `(901,234)` from `friendReq` and add that relationship to `friends`. There are no profile pages here--no Facebook-style "respond to friend request" option. It's a simple follower-based app whereby friendships are requested by simply typing their username and clicking add.

My functioning SQL for simply adding a friend request without checking for the stuff I just described:

```
INSERT INTO friendReq ( initBy, reqTo)
    VALUES ($userid, (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$addFriend') );
```

(`$addFriend` is gotten from the username that that a given user types in to send the friend request; please no comments on preventing SQL injection, this is just my simplified sample.)

Pseudo-code, supposing `234` sends a request to `901`:

```
IF (234, 901) DOES NOT EXIST
    INSERT INTO friendReq ( initBy, reqTo)
        VALUES ( 234, 901 )
IF (901, 234) EXISTS
    INSERT INTO friends (901, 234),
    DELETE FROM friendReq (901, 234);
```

My apologies if my explanation is not very clear. Any suggestions?

---

**Solution**:
I'm not sure if this is SOP around here, but for anyone else looking, below is what I ended up doing and it works. I'm sure there are some efficiency improvements to be done (for example, building the various query strings from other strings instead of retyping many parts of it, as well as using multi_query), but for a simple solution, hopefully someone finds this of use:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM friendReq
          WHERE initBy = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$addFriend')
          AND reqTo = $userid";
if ( mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $query) ) == 1 ) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM friendReq
              WHERE initBy = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$addFriend')
              AND reqTo = $userid";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $query = "INSERT INTO friends (user1, user2)
              VALUES ($userid, (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$addFriend') )";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    die();
} else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO friendReq (initBy, reqTo)
              VALUES ($userid, (SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$addFriend') )";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    die();
}
```

Comment: have you solved this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer this without actual code because I am in a hurry. You already have this mostly setup and I like your layout.

Try to insert into friendReq and get the number of rows inserted. If one row inserted then done, if 0 rows inserted, then delete opposite friend request and insert into friends.

This solution is not 100% mysql but will take php as well.

Comment: I ended up going with this. I couldn't get memnoch_proxy's answer working for some reason, but this I understood better and the php is fine as this is a web app. Thanks!

Comment: @andrewmc no problem, sorry I couldn't include code for others, I may go back when I have some more spare time and work this solution all the way out with code.

Comment: no worries. I went ahead and edited my initial post to include my working PHP solution for anyone else looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd find `INSERT IGNORE` and `DELETE IGNORE` easier syntax to use.

Given :
    CREATE TABLE friendReq (
      `initBy` int(11),
      `reqTo` int(11),
      UNIQUE KEY `urel` (`initBy`, `reqTo`)
    );

This allows you to write an insert statement without messing about with `EXISTS` clauses:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO friendReq (initBy, reqTo) VALUES ( 234, 901 );
INSERT IGNORE INTO friends (901, 234);
DELETE IGNORE FROM friendReq WHERE initBy=901 AND reqTo=234;
```

If you add a `done` column to you friendReq table, you could take advantage of the [on duplicate key update][1 syntax. Then you update a flag column and don't have to lock for a delete. You would defer your deletes until they were handled by a cron process, reducing read-write contention on the table:

```
INSERT INTO friendReq( initBy, reqTo, done) VALUES(234, 901, 0)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE done=1;
```